# I want to get the first DOM object but not the property of the first object

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

There are 3 tag `a` in the HTML Document. As following:

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <a href="#" tabindex="1" class="active_nav">nav1</a>
    <a href="#" tabindex="2">nav2</a>
    <a href="#"tabindex="3">nav3</a>
</nav>
```

I use jquery selector expect to get the first `<a>` like this

```
alert($("#navigation >a")[0]);
```

but it shows the href property of the 1st `<a>` !!!!!

If I replace  `<a>`  with `<div>` , it works.

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <div >nav1</div>
    <div >nav2</div>
    <div >nav3</div>
</nav>
```

when  alert($("#navigation >div")[0]); it shows the 1st DOM object. 
I think it very strange. Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `toString` of an `HTMLAnchorElement` just returns the `href` property.

```
$("#navigation > a")[0];           // HTMLAnchorElement
$("#navigation >a")[0].href;       // "http://example.com/#"
$("#navigation >a")[0].toString(); // "http://example.com/#"
```

`alert` only takes a string as an argument, so `toString` is automatically called on your Element and you end up seeing the `href` property.

You should use `console.log` for debugging, not `alert`. It is many times more useful.

Comment: @bohan Because `.text` is a jQuery function, so you need a jQuery object to use it on, not an HTMLAnchorElement. Both the following would work: `$($("#navigation > a")[0]).text("..");` and this one is better: `$("#navigation > a").eq(0).text("..")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these.

```
alert($("#navigation > a").first().text());
```

or

```
alert($("#navigation > a").first().html());
```

Answer (score 0):

The square braces mean a different thing, it accesses the `HTMLElement` of the first object in the matched set. What you're looking for is `.eq` (specifically `.eq(0)`) and like @Paulpro said, `alert` forces `toString`.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/eq/